# context into adapter error in fragment

Tags: android, gridview, fragment, android-adapter, android-context

why when I put  fragment into my adapter and it should get context from fragment when i run it , log cat gives me error:

```
@Override
public void onActivityCreated(Bundle arg0)
{
    super.onActivityCreated(arg0);
    mygrid= (GridView) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.gridView2);
    mygrid.setAdapter(new Myaddapter(getActivity().getApplicationContext()));
```

Logcat output:

```
05-23 22:28:33.862: E/AndroidRuntime(1650): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
05-23 22:28:33.862: E/AndroidRuntime(1650): Process: com.amirhossein.simon, PID: 1650
05-23 22:28:33.862: E/AndroidRuntime(1650): java.lang.NullPointerException
05-23 22:28:33.862: E/AndroidRuntime(1650):     at com.amirhossein.simon.FragmentA.<init>(FragmentA.java:33)
05-23 22:28:33.862: E/AndroidRuntime(1650):     at com.amirhossein.simon.Myadapter.getItem(Fragment1.java:100)
05-23 22:28:33.862: E/AndroidRuntime(1650):     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentPagerAdapter.instantiateItem(FragmentPagerAdapter.java:97)
05-23 22:28:33.862: E/AndroidRuntime(1650):     at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.addNewItem(ViewPager.java:832)
05-23 22:28:33.862: E/AndroidRuntime(1650):     at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.populate(ViewPager.java:982)
05-23 22:28:33.862: E/AndroidRuntime(1650):     at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.populate(ViewPager.java:914)
05-23 22:28:33.862: E/AndroidRuntime(1650):     at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.onMeasure(ViewPager.java:1436)
05-23 22:28:33.862: E/AndroidRuntime(1650):     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:16497)
05-23 22:28:33.862: E/AndroidRuntime(1650):     at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5125)
05-23 22:28:33.862: E/AndroidRuntime(1650):     at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:310)
05-23 22:28:33.862: E/AndroidRuntime(1650):     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:16497)
05-23 22:28:33.862: E/AndroidRuntime(1650):     at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5125)
05-23 22:28:33.862: E/AndroidRuntime(1650):     at com.android.internal.widget.ActionBarOverlayLayout.onMeasure(ActionBarOverlayLayout.java:327)
05-23 22:28:33.862: E/AndroidRuntime(1650):     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:16497)
05-23 22:28:33.862: E/AndroidRuntime(1650):     at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5125)
05-23 22:28:33.862: E/AndroidRuntime(1650):     at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:310)
05-23 22:28:33.862: E/AndroidRuntime(1650):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.onMeasure(PhoneWindow.java:2291)
05-23 22:28:33.862: E/AndroidRuntime(1650):     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:16497)
05-23 22:28:33.862: E/AndroidRuntime(1650):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performMeasure(ViewRootImpl.java:1916)
05-23 22:28:33.862: E/AndroidRuntime(1650):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.measureHierarchy(ViewRootImpl.java:1113)
05-23 22:28:33.862: E/AndroidRuntime(1650):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1295)
05-23 22:28:33.862: E/AndroidRuntime(1650):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1000)
05-23 22:28:33.862: E/AndroidRuntime(1650):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:5670)
05-23 22:28:33.862: E/AndroidRuntime(1650):     at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:761)
05-23 22:28:33.862: E/AndroidRuntime(1650):     at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:574)
05-23 22:28:33.862: E/AndroidRuntime(1650):     at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:544)
05-23 22:28:33.862: E/AndroidRuntime(1650):     at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:747)
05-23 22:28:33.862: E/AndroidRuntime(1650):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
05-23 22:28:33.862: E/AndroidRuntime(1650):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
05-23 22:28:33.862: E/AndroidRuntime(1650):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
05-23 22:28:33.862: E/AndroidRuntime(1650):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017)
05-23 22:28:33.862: E/AndroidRuntime(1650):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
05-23 22:28:33.862: E/AndroidRuntime(1650):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
05-23 22:28:33.862: E/AndroidRuntime(1650):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
05-23 22:28:33.862: E/AndroidRuntime(1650):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595)
05-23 22:28:33.862: E/AndroidRuntime(1650):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: Looks like a member initializer that's causing the exception. What's on FragmentA.java, line 33?

Comment: it is in line 33 : GridView mygrid= (GridView) getView().findViewById(R.id.gridView1);

Answer (score 0):

```
GridView mygrid= (GridView) getView().findViewById(R.id.gridView1);
```

You cannot obtain views in member initializers. You can keep the member declaration, but the initialization code should be moved into the Fragment's `onCreateView()` (by using `findViewById()` on the view you are returning, not on `getView()`).